# How to add gradient to a border line below the header of a page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can i add gradient to a border line below the header of a page in Xamarin Forms?

An example of what i want to achieve is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL3DI.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i add gradient to a border line below the header of a page in Xamarin Forms?

I create custom render to create gradient border.

Firstly, you need to define render:

```
public class GradientViewRender : View
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty GradientColorsProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GradientViewRender, Color[]>(p => p.GradientColors, new Color[]{Color.White} );

    public Color[] GradientColors
    {
        get { return (Color[])base.GetValue(GradientColorsProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(GradientColorsProperty, value); }
    }

    
    public static readonly BindableProperty ViewHeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GradientViewRender, double>(p => p.ViewHeight, 0);

    public double ViewHeight
    {
        get { return (double)base.GetValue(ViewHeightProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ViewHeightProperty, value); }
    }


    
    public static readonly BindableProperty LeftToRightProperty = BindableProperty.Create<GradientViewRender, bool>(p => p.LeftToRight, true);

    public bool LeftToRight
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(LeftToRightProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(LeftToRightProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This render takes in an array of Colors, this way you can supply as many colors as needed for your gradient.

Then you can implement this render in android .

```
public class GradientViewRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer<GradientTest.GradientViewRender, View>
{
    LinearLayout layout;
    Xamarin.Forms.Color[] gradientColors;
   
    double viewHeight;
    

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<GradientTest.GradientViewRender> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            layout = new LinearLayout(Application.Context);
            layout.SetBackgroundColor(Color.White);
        
            gradientColors = (Xamarin.Forms.Color[])e.NewElement.GradientColors;
            
            viewHeight = (double)e.NewElement.ViewHeight;
            

            CreateLayout();
        }

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe from event handlers and cleanup any resources
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            // Configure the control and subscribe to event handlers
            gradientColors = (Xamarin.Forms.Color[])e.NewElement.GradientColors;
            
            viewHeight = (double)e.NewElement.ViewHeight;
            

            CreateLayout();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == GradientViewRender.ViewHeightProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            this.viewHeight = (double)this.Element.ViewHeight;
            CreateLayout();
        }
        
        else if (e.PropertyName == GradientViewRender.GradientColorsProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            this.gradientColors = (Xamarin.Forms.Color[])this.Element.GradientColors;
            CreateLayout();
        }
        
        
    }

    private void CreateLayout()
    {
        layout.SetMinimumWidth((int)viewWidth);
        layout.SetMinimumHeight((int)viewHeight);

        CreateGradient();

        SetNativeControl(layout);
    }

    public void CreateGradient()
    {
        //Need to convert the colors to Android Color objects
        int[] androidColors = new int[gradientColors.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < gradientColors.Count(); i++)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Color temp = gradientColors[i];
            androidColors[i] = temp.ToAndroid();
        }

        GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LeftRight, androidColors);

        if (roundCorners)
            gradient.SetCornerRadii(new float[] { cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius });

        layout.SetBackground(gradient);
    }
}
```

About more detailed info, you can take a look:

https://baglabs.com/2017/07/14/creating-gradients-xamarin-forms/

You can get samle from:

https://github.com/baileysh9/xamarin_forms_gradient

Finally, you can get this gradient border like this:

[image]

You can change different color by GradientColors.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Xamarin.Forms view with a custom renderer that draws a gradient in the view for iOS and Android. Then place that view wherever you want it, presumably just below the header or title bar.

First read the docs on making Custom renderers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

I tried this starting from a Xamarin.Forms Box View.

**First create a new class in the Xamarin.Forms core shared project that inherits from BoxView and sets 3 bindable properties for the start, middle and end colors:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class GradientView : BoxView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty StartColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(StartColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(GradientView),
                Color.Transparent);

        public Color StartColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Color)GetValue(StartColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(StartColorProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty MiddleColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(MiddleColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(GradientView),
                Color.Transparent);

        public Color MiddleColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Color)GetValue(MiddleColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(MiddleColorProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly BindableProperty EndColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(EndColor),
                typeof(Color),
                typeof(GradientView),
                Color.Transparent);

        public Color EndColor
        {
            get
            {
                return (Color)GetValue(EndColorProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(EndColorProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Use the above view in your XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestUITest"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                x:Class="TestUITest.MainPage"
                Title="Gradient View"
                BackgroundColor="Black">
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <local:GradientView
            StartColor="DarkBlue"
            MiddleColor="LightBlue"
            EndColor="DarkBlue"
            HeightRequest="5" />
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               TextColor="White"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Also set your nav bar to black (to match your screenshot), so in your Xamarin.Forms App class:**

```
public App()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        var navPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

        navPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        navPage.BarTextColor = Color.LightBlue;

        MainPage = navPage;
}
```

**Now for the Platform specific renderers:**

**Android:**

```
using System;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using YourNameSpace;
using YourNameSpace.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientView),typeof(GradientViewRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.Droid
{
    public class GradientViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {
        public GradientViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<BoxView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                GradientView formsGradientView = Element as GradientView;

                int[] colors = {
                   Convert.ToInt32(formsGradientView.StartColor.ToHex().Replace("#", "0x"), 16),
                   Convert.ToInt32(formsGradientView.MiddleColor.ToHex().Replace("#", "0x"), 16),
                   Convert.ToInt32(formsGradientView.EndColor.ToHex().Replace("#", "0x"), 16)
                };

                var gradeDrawable = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.LeftRight, colors);
                ViewGroup.SetBackgroundDrawable(gradeDrawable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**iOS:**

```
using System;
using CoreAnimation;
using CoreGraphics;
using YourNameSpace;
using YourNameSpace.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientView), typeof(GradientViewRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class GradientViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {

        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            //base.Draw(rect);
            GradientView formsGradientView = Element as GradientView;

            var currentContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
            currentContext.SaveState();

            var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();

            var startColor = formsGradientView.StartColor;
            var startColorComponents = startColor.ToCGColor().Components;

            var middleColor = formsGradientView.MiddleColor;
            var middleColorComponents = middleColor.ToCGColor().Components;

            var endColor = formsGradientView.EndColor;
            var endColorComponents = endColor.ToCGColor().Components;

            nfloat[] colorComponents = {
                startColorComponents[0], startColorComponents[1], startColorComponents[2], startColorComponents[3],
                middleColorComponents[0], middleColorComponents[1], middleColorComponents[2], middleColorComponents[3],
                endColorComponents[0], endColorComponents[1], endColorComponents[2], endColorComponents[3]
            };

            nfloat[] locations = { 0f, 0.5f, 1f };

            var gradient = new CGGradient(colorSpace, colorComponents, locations);

            var startPoint = new CGPoint(0, NativeView.Bounds.Height);
            var endPoint = new CGPoint(NativeView.Bounds.Width, NativeView.Bounds.Height);

            currentContext.DrawLinearGradient(gradient, startPoint, endPoint, CGGradientDrawingOptions.None);
            currentContext.RestoreState();

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i dont now why, but i have error in this code Convert.ToInt32(formsGradientView.MiddleColor.ToHex().Replace("#", "0x"), 16), its tell ToHex() Not Exists